# How to convert a 3 input AND gate into a NOR gate?

Tags: boolean-logic, circuit-diagram

I know that I can say convert a 2-input AND gate into a NOR gate by simply inverting the two inputs because of DeMorgan's Theorem.

But how would you do the equivalent on a 3-input AND gate?

Say...

```
     ____
A___|     \
B___|      )___ 
C___|____ /
```

I'm trying to understand this because my homework asks me to take a circuit and convert it using NOR synthesis to only use nor gates, and I know how to do it with 2 input gates, but the gate with 3 inputs is throwing me for a spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeMorgan's theorem for 2-input AND would produce:

```
AB
(AB)''
(A' + B')'
```

So, yes, the inputs are inverted and fed into a NOR gate.

DeMorgan's theorem for 3-input AND would similarly produce:

```
ABC
(ABC)''
(A' + B' + C')'
```

Which is, again, inputs inverted and fed into a (3-input) NOR gate:

```
     ___
A--O\    \
B--O )    )O--- 
C--O/___ /
```

@SailorChibi has truth tables that show equivalence.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this might be how u do it, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

If i haven't made any mistakes it is pretty much the same, invert all 3 of the inputs and you get a NOR

**Table:**

AND with inverted in is exact the same as

```
1 1 1 = 1           
1 1 1 = 0           
1 0 1 = 0           
0 1 0 = 0           
0 1 1 = 0           
0 1 0 = 0           
0 0 1 = 0           
0 0 0 = 0
```

NOR with original input

```
0 0 0 = 1            
0 0 1 = 0            
0 1 0 = 0            
1 0 1 = 0            
1 0 0 = 0            
1 0 1 = 0            
1 1 0 = 0            
1 1 1 = 0
```

Comment: By your logic I was able to understand this, thank you! Though I feel like there is something wrong with the input columns of your truth table. On the 4th row?